# Is there a way in laravel 4 to create custom validation message in fly

Tags: php, laravel

In laravel 4  you can create custom validation error message by adding it to `$this->messages` array. But in my case, I need to add it at runtime, when a custom validation rule is processing.

For example I have such custom rule:

```
        Validator::extend('isCityNamesValid', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
            $value = array_map('trim', explode("\n", $value));
            if(empty($value)) {
                return true;
            }
            $invalidNames = \City::getInvalidCityNames($value, $parameters);
            if(!empty($invalidNames)) {
                $this->messages[$attribute.'.is_city_names_valid'] = sprintf('You provide invalid city names for selected countries, please remove/fix these names: %s.', implode(', ', $invalidNames));
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        });
```

In this custom rule, I'm creating message only when the rule is failing and I'm appending custom data to the message. Is it possible without overriding default laravel `passes` method? or I need to make such validation without using laravel validation mechanism?

Comment: Perhaps you should read the documentation on Validation in Laravel (specifically version 4.2): https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#custom-error-messages

Comment: I read it but as you can see I'm appending dynamic data `$invalidNames` to message,  `$this->messages[$attribute.'.is_city_names_valid'] = sprintf('You provide invalid city names for selected countries, please remove/fix these names: %s.', implode(', ', $invalidNames));` and I can't find any information  in the documentation about how to do this

Comment: In documentation, they passing messages array when making new validator instance, but in my case message is not defined at that point, I'm defining message when rule is failing